# Reading a form-field in sencha touch extjs

Tags: forms, sencha-touch, extjs-mvc

I have a form field and i want to read the text entered into it, i tried the following code:

```
this.searchButton = new Ext.Button({// The button press will invoke the search action
            text: 'Go',
            handler: this.searchButtonTap,
            scope: this
        });

this.topToolbar = new Ext.form.FormPanel({
                   items: [

                    {xtype: 'textfield',
                    name: 'search',
                    placeHolder: 'Search'},
                    this.searchButton

                ]
        });

 searchButtonTap: function () {
       // console.log(this.topToolbar.items.items[1]);
       var currentText = AsApp.views.AsListView.getRecord();
        console.log(currentText);
    },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may try this:

```
this.searchField = new Ext.form.Text({
            displayField: 'name',
            valueField: 'name',
            editable: true,
            forceSelection: true,
            triggerAction: 'all',
            emptyText: 'Search...',
            selectOnFocus: true
    });

this.searchButton = new Ext.Button({// The button press will invoke the search action
        text: 'Go',
        handler: this.searchButtonTap,
        scope: this
    });

    this.topToolbar = new Ext.Toolbar({
                   items: [
                { xtype: 'spacer' },    
                    this.searchField,
                    this.searchButton,
                    { xtype: 'spacer' },
                ]
        });



searchButtonTap: function () {
    var searchText = this.searchField.getValue();
    console.log(searchText);

    },
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the value of a textfield, use the field's getValue() method.

For example:

```
var field = myTextField;
var currentText = field.getValue();
```

You can also use `searchfield` instead of `textfield`. It also has the getValue() method available.

Comment: could you please define the myTextField thing, what does it refer to in the above case.

Comment: myTextField can just point to whatever your textfield is. I'm assuming  your "this.topToolbar.items.items[1]" is pointing to it, but in your handler, since you've passed the scope into it, you should just be able to do something like "var currentText = this.getValue();" from your searchButtonTap function.